# React application: all three buttons get clicked by themselves, how do I stop that from happening (very new to react)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

This is my function that calls the API: at the bottom are the two buttons that get clicked automatically. Any help is would be very helpful since I am a beginner to react and js

```
postData = m => {
    const config = {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        apiRegistrationId: "46",
      },
    };
    const data = {
      referenceNumber: "string",
      sourceRequestId: m
    };

    axios
      .post(
        "https://gateway-web.beta.greenhouse.ca/publicapi",
        data,
        config
      )
      .then((data) => {
        console.log(data.GatewayUrl);
        window.location.href = data.GatewayUrl;
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Donate to the local food shelter</h1>
        <button onClick={this.postData(5)}>Donate $5</button>
        <button onClick={this.postData(10)}>Donate $10</button> 
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Home;
```

Comment: `this.postData(5)` **calls the method** (with an argument it, incidentally, doesn't actually do anything with) and passes the *result* to `onClick`. Did you mean e.g. `onClick={() => this.postData()}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass it a function... Just do

```
  <button onClick={() => this.postData(5)}>Donate $5</button>
  <button onClick={() => this.postData(10)}>Donate $10</button>
```

or change `postData = m => {` to `postData = () => m => {`

Comment: I'd add on here that `onClick` requires a value, which it stores and calls when the component is clicked. You can explicitly put a value there (like 5) or a function (getOnClickFunction). If you put a function, the value stored for `onClick` is the return value of that function, which has to be obtained by actually calling it on render.